# socket.io keep repeating fail request

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have strange issue. Basically the client will send a request i.e:delete chat, but Server will reject, since client is not authorized.

however, the client keep repeating the same request, even if I open new browser and load the same address. Both browser will keep requesting the previous action. my code looks something like this:

Client

```
socket.on(username, (res) => {
     show(res.err)
})
socket.send({
   type: "delete_chat",
   username: username,
   id: chat_id
})
```

Server:

```
io.sockets.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.on("message", (data) => {
         if(data.type === "delete_chat"){
              Chat.delete(chatid, (err, res) => {
                 io.emit(username, {err:res}) //send error to username  

              });                 
         }
    })
})
```

Comment: Post error message you are receiving.  What do you means by "Server will reject"